# How can I incorporate JS libraries into my NPM build script?

Tags: javascript, npm

My current site is build with html+css (scss) and using a NPM build script (see below). I now want to add a few JS libraries to my website (for example: lozad).

So far I've downloaded the dependencies for it. As I'm not familiar with JS, I don't understand the other steps I need to take. I tried following [the documentation](https://github.com/ApoorvSaxena/lozad.js) but it's not working so far.

I now assume that this is because my current NPM build script doesn't track JS, so any JS wouldn't be shown on my devserver. So maybe it did work, but just not in test?

Can anyone point me in the direction of what I need to do to make it working, and/or how to update my NPM script?

```
  "scripts": {
    "watch:sass": "node-sass sass/main.scss css/style.css -w",
    "devserver": "live-server --browser=firefox",
    "start": "npm-run-all --parallel devserver watch:sass",
    "compile:sass": "node-sass sass/main.scss css/style.comp.css",
    "concat:css": "concat -o css/style.concat.css css/icon-font.css css/style.comp.css",
    "prefix:css": "postcss --use autoprefixer -b 'last 10 versions' css/style.concat.css -o css/style.prefix.css",
    "compress:css": "node-sass css/style.prefix.css css/style.css --output-style compressed",
    "build:css": "npm-run-all compile:sass concat:css prefix:css compress:css"
  },

  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^9.6.0",
    "concat": "^1.0.3",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
    "postcss-cli": "^6.1.2",
    "webpack": "^4.35.3",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.6"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "aos": "^2.3.4",
    "lozad": "^1.9.0",

  }
}
```

Comment: I guess you want to use new JS libraries on front-end. Your `webpack` is responsible for building result js files that are used on pages. But I don't see it's executions in npm scripts, probably it is triggered somehow separately. How are you going to use lozad if you are not familiar with JS, as you say?

Comment: I've only just installed webpack. I haven't set it up yet nor am I familiar with it. It's one of the solutions I'm exploring right now. So, nothing is triggered separately ;)

My idea was just to implement lozad on my site for lazy loading of the images. From what I gathered, I just needed to change my html tags and get the JS library to run, without doing any JS programming myself

Comment: Ok, I'll suggest not change npm and no `npm install --save lozad`. Just use `script` tag from the lib description page (CDN) to add it to your html pages.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to give the relative path to the dependency and run the script like so:

```
"scripts": {
   ...
   "lozad": "npm run ./node_modules/lozad/index.js --argument"
}
```

Note that this is only assumed data. The real path and file are probably called something else (Just look into the node:modules folder for lozad).

According [to this article,](https://firstdoit.com/no-need-for-globals-using-npm-dependencies-in-npm-scripts-3dfb478908) you can also omit the path and the npm rum when there is a .bin folder for that dependency, but I have not tested that.

### Edit

In case you meant on how to use the library locally.

You have to add the package to your dependencies (Like you did) and then call

```
npm install
```

in your project directory. It will install all your dependencies specified in `package.json`.

You can omit the manual "add dependency to file" step by simply calling:

```
npm install --save lozad
```

After that you can use it in your project like so:

```
// using ES6 modules
import lozad from 'lozad'

// using CommonJS modules
var lozad = require('lozad')
```

If you don't know which one to use, just try them - your IDE will tell you if something is wrong.

When you imported the library, you can use it like [described at the Usage Description.](https://github.com/ApoorvSaxena/lozad.js#usage)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, Maurice. 

Here's what I don't understand (and I fully understand that this is because I know nothing about JS): Where do I add the " import lozad from 'lozad' "? In a separate JS file?

Comment: Where do you want to use lozad? @TomvanRheeden

Comment: On a static website? (I'm not trying to be smart, this is literally the best answer I can come up with)

Comment: Yeah but you probably have some JavaScript Code. Where is this Code and what is it used for?

Comment: Nope, it was all CSS so far. So I haven't set up any JS structure.